# convert json to array using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

The result of my php is

```
     $result = '[{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.59"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.87"},{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-APR-14|0.25"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-APR-14|0.67"},{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAY-14|0.10"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAY-14|0.03"}]';
```

and done json parse to it

```
    var data = new Array();
     data = JSON.parse('<?php echo $result ; ?>');
```

How will I get the output as

```
   MFG_NAME[0] = ABC;
   MFG_NAME[1] = XYZ;
   DATE[0] = [01-MAR-14,01-APR-14,01-MAY-14];
   DATE[1] = [01-MAR-14,01-APR-14,01-MAY-14];
   MKT[0] = [0.59,0.25,0.10];
   MKT[1] = [0.87,0.67,0.03];
```

Comment: `data[0].MFG_NAME` will get you `ABC`

Comment: what you got in data?

Comment: @AyyanarG I can't display it because it will be in object form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through `data`, building your arrays.  First check to see if you already have a matching `MFG_NAME` by using `indexOf()`.  If you have a match, use that index for the other arrays.  Otherwise create new entries for each variable.

```js
var data = [
    { MFG_NAME: "ABC", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-MAR-14|0.59" },
    { MFG_NAME: "XYZ", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-MAR-14|0.87" },
    { MFG_NAME: "ABC", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-APR-14|0.25" },
    { MFG_NAME: "XYZ", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-APR-14|0.67" },
    { MFG_NAME: "ABC", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-MAY-14|0.10" },
    { MFG_NAME: "XYZ", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-MAY-14|0.03" }
];

var MFG_NAME = [];
var DATE = [];
var MKT = [];

data.forEach(function(item) {
    var parts = item.CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.split("|");
    var i = MFG_NAME.indexOf(item.MFG_NAME);
    if (i == -1) {
        MFG_NAME.push(item.MFG_NAME);
        DATE.push([parts.shift()]);
        MKT.push([+parts.shift()]);
    }
    else {
        DATE[i].push(parts.shift());
        MKT[i].push(+parts.shift());
    }
});

var success = MFG_NAME[0] == "ABC" &&
    MFG_NAME[1] == "XYZ" &&
    DATE[0].join(",") == "01-MAR-14,01-APR-14,01-MAY-14" &&
    DATE[1].join(",") == "01-MAR-14,01-APR-14,01-MAY-14" &&
    MKT[0].join(",") == "0.59,0.25,0.1" &&
    MKT[1].join(",") == "0.87,0.67,0.03";

document.write(success);
```

This requires your data to be sorted by date.  Your sample data is already sorted by date then name.  This will still work if it's sorted by name then date, or if it's sorted by only date, not considering name at all.  **But**, If it's not sorted by date at all, you'll need to do an extra step to sort first (which would be inefficient), or adjust the code to sort as you process the data.

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = '[{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.59"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.87"},{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-APR-14|0.25"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-APR-14|0.67"},{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAY-14|0.10"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAY-14|0.03"}];';

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Maybe it's your solution?!

Comment: How does this split up the data into separate arrays?

Comment: $result = 'JSON';
$i = 0;
foreach( $result as $item){
 $arr[$i] = $item;
 $i++;
}
var_dump($arr);

Like this? Or what you need?

Comment: You can write $arr = json_decode($result); And after that you will have array with arrays from each of JSON objects.

Comment: I added 'true' in 'json_decode($result, true)' so that should be associated array.

Comment: @SkyStar I need arrays as my output and for each MFG_NAME there must be DATE array and MKT array not a combined array of all MFG_NAME

Answer (score -1):

**I guess this is what you want:**

```
var $result = '[{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.59"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.87"},{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-APR-14|0.25"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-APR-14|0.67"},{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAY-14|0.10"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAY-14|0.03"}]';
    var data = new Array();
    data = JSON.parse($result);
    var MFG_NAME = new Array();
    var DATE = new Array();
    var MKT = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        MFG_NAME[i] = value.MFG_NAME;
        var MKT_SHARE = value['CONCATED_MKT_SHARE'].split('|');
        DATE[i] = MKT_SHARE[0];
        MKT[i] = MKT_SHARE[1];

        i++;
    });
    console.log(MFG_NAME[0]);
    console.log(MFG_NAME[1]);
    console.log(MFG_NAME);
    console.log(DATE);
    console.log(MKT);
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/1n51kwze/

Answer (score -1):

```
var MFG_NAME = [];
var DATE = [];
var MKT = [];
//For each data entry
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    concatString = data[i]["CONCATED_MKT_SHARE"].split("|");
    //If name not exists create date and mkt object for name instance
    if(MFG_NAME.indexOf(data[i]["MFG_NAME"]) == -1){
        MFG_NAME[i] = data[i]["MFG_NAME"];
        DATE[i] = [];
        MKT[i] = [];
        DATE[i].push(concatString[0]);
        MKT[i].push(concatString[1]);   
    }else{
        //Else just add to existing
        DATE[MFG_NAME.indexOf(data[i]["MFG_NAME"])].push(concatString[0]);
        MKT[MFG_NAME.indexOf(data[i]["MFG_NAME"])].push(concatString[1]);   
    }
}   

    console.log(MFG_NAME[0]);
    console.log(MFG_NAME[1]);
    console.log(DATE[0]);
    console.log(DATE[1]);
    console.log(MKT[0]);
    console.log(MKT[1]);
```

Result looks like this:

```
ABC
XYZ
["01-MAR-14", "01-APR-14", "01-MAY-14"]
["01-MAR-14", "01-APR-14", "01-MAY-14"]
["0.59", "0.25", "0.10"]
["0.87", "0.67", "0.03"]
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `substring`? `new Array()`? Global variables? Temporary variables with random names you only use once? That's pretty inefficient coding.

Answer (score -2):

You could do that like this:

```js
var data = [{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.59"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.87"},{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-APR-14|0.25"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-APR-14|0.67"},{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAY-14|0.10"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAY-14|0.03"}];

var MFG_NAME = [],
    DATE = [],
    MKT = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    MFG_NAME.push(data[i].MFG_NAME);
    var split = data[i].CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.split("|");
    DATE.push(split[0]);
    MKT.push(split[1]);
}

alert("MFG_NAME:\n" + JSON.stringify(MFG_NAME) + "\n\n" +
      "DATE:\n" + JSON.stringify(DATE) + "\n\n" +
      "MKT:\n" + JSON.stringify(MKT));
```

As you can see, this will result in 3 new arrays containing your data, separated by key.

Oh, and you don't need to declare `data` before adding properties to it. This'll work just fine:

```
var data = JSON.parse('<?php echo $result ; ?>');
```

Comment: This gives a combined array. I want separate arrays for ABC and XYZ in a loop

Comment: Oh, I see... Why do you need the data formatted like that?

Comment: @Cerbus To pass the arrays to high charts. I am very bad and new to arrays. SO I'm struggling with it

Comment: Hm, the desired output is a little complex to get... I'm not sure how I'd approach that right now.

Comment: ya its complex. That is why I am asking for help. Please try, even I am also trying since 2 days